# ApexCharts stacked area's + area with multiple y-axis issue

Tags: area, apexcharts, yaxis, stacked

I'm trying to create a chart with ApexCharts with 3 data elements:

`First Time Visitors`

`Returning Visitors`

`Page Views`

The first 2 should be in a stacked configuration as they together form the `Total Visitors` amount. So I added `stacked: true` to these data series.

The `page views` should be plotted against a secondary y-axis as the numbers can be very different from the visitors counts.

At https://codepen.io/golabs/pen/jORENBv you can find my efforts so far.

My issue is that `Returning Visitors` seems to be plotted to an additional y-axis and is not added on top of the `First Time Visitors area`... it drives me nuts to be honest as I don't see what I'm doing wrong here.

Anyone an idea how I can get this fixed?

Unfortunately the documentation and the examples don't provide the solution to me :(

Comment: It looks like this is NOT possible at all... too bad as it would have been nice. I could use a rangeArea for the 2 visitors related lines but that looks pretty confusing so I'm now back to lines for everything. Returning Visitors will become Total Visitors. When my final setup is ready I'll post a new codepen example.